# How was this plotter image created?

Tags: plotter

This image (from a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75902803/producing-a-partial-axis-in-matplotlib))

[image]

resonated with my forgotten memories, in particular

1. the Tek4014 thermal printer,
2. a Fortran plotting library, whose name I forgot, possibly associated with a Calcomp plotter.

Could you help me to fully recover how the image was produced?

---

The only tag I could come up with is [printer] (e.g., pen-plotter is not a tag), I hope that you can add other relevant tags, tia.

Comment: You haven't given much to go on, but I used GINO-F in the mid 1970s to draw similiar-looking graphs on a Calcomp pen plotter.

Comment: @another-dave At least I TRIED to give you all the info I have, and not to hide anything I know!

Comment: I added a plotter tag.

Comment: It might be helpful to specify what exactly you are looking for - for example is it about Software or Hardware, Devices or Data?

Comment: Quite possibly a creation of a graphic artist from multiple computer generated bits.

Comment: If you mean "which software" by "how", I wouldn't be surprised if there are lots of libraries/applications that could create something similar. The equations are somewhat distinctive, though, but good luck pinpointing the library that produced them in this particular way.

Comment: If you want to know how exactly that plot was made, ask the person who wrote the question you linked to.